# SQL '08: How to count all sku's in one table not found in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I would like to do something similar to this psuedo-SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.SKU) 
  FROM TableA as A
 WHERE a.sku NOT IN TableB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple solutions, example with EXISTS :

```
SELECT COUNT(A.SKU) AS your_count
FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                 FROM TableB
                 WHERE B.SKU = A.SKU);
```

You could also use EXCEPT :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT SKU
    FROM TableA
    EXCEPT
    SELECT SKU
    FROM TableB);
```

You could also use NOT IN, LEFT OUTER JOIN ... WHERE B.SKU IS NULL, etc.

Comment: is the second examp for mysql cuz i be gettin errors::::::Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXCEPT'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Line 7: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: MySQL doesn't know EXCEPT, but considering you said you were using SQL Server, it should work.

Comment: @bizness: Are you using the Compact Edition, by chance?

Comment: yeah for ur second examp i just get incorrect syntax near EXCEPT:::    SELECT SKU
    FROM PartProductSupplemental

    EXCEPT

    SELECT SKU
    FROM Inventory

Comment: @bizness: What is the compatibility for the database set at?  In Management Studio, right click on the database name under the "Databases" heading in the Object Explorer.  In the Properties window that pops up, select "Options" - Compatibility Level is third from the top.